# mod_cluster-manager returns blank page

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, httpd.conf, mod-cluster

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1 Final with mod_cluster 1.2.0.

I've configured HTTPD as follows: `http://pastebin.com/C1rnWc1U`

However when I try to reach the page `http://10.0.0.6:10001/mod_cluster-manager/` it returns a blank page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rl8u.jpg

Comment: It's preferable to have 1) your configuration inside the question, and 2) your screenshot as an image. Put your configuration into your question by clicking `edit` underneath your question, paste the configuration, select the configuration you pasted and click the `{}` button the highlight it. The same for your image: edit your question, click the image button and supply the link to your image (post it on https://imgur.com/ to get a proper link).

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

That is correct. Unless there are worker nodes connected, there is nothing to display.

## Do not use vulnerable code

Please, *do not* use mod_cluster 1.2.0 with your Apache HTTP Server. The version is completely obsolete and it contains serious bugs, including a code injection CVE and severe performance issue. Download [mod_cluster 1.3.1.Final for httpd 2.4.x](http://modcluster.io/change_log/#final-6-may-2015) or build your own [from the sources](http://modcluster.io/documentation/#building-httpd-modules), if you desire httpd 2.2.x support. If you happen to need any any help with that, ask.